# How to allow derived classes to return any iterator over a type through a virtual method?

Tags: c++11, templates, iterator, return-value, virtual-functions

I am trying to write a little library which allows the user to implement certain behaviours so that the library may work with his own underlying data structure. In this particular case (although I'm simplifying), I'm trying to define something like this:

```cpp
class LibraryClass {
    virtual std::vector<int>::const_iterator intsBegin() const = 0;
    virtual std::vector<int>::const_iterator intsEnd() const = 0;
};
```

In other words, the library will accept working with any derived class which allows it to iterate over a vector of integers. Now the tricky bit is: *I don't want to force the use of vectors*. Really, any iterator over integers is okay for me, as long as I can detect when it ends, and dereference it to an integer. Here's the missing bit:

```cpp
class LibraryClass {
    virtual /* ??? */ intsBegin() const = 0;
    virtual /* ??? */ intsEnd() const = 0;
};

class UserClass {
    /* This should be allowed, here I'm using vector as an example. */
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator intsBegin() const;
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator intsEnd() const;
};
```

Now, I know how to have [that kind of behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5054087/2228310) through templates for method parameters, but I can't find a way to have it for a return value in a virtual method, given that:

- Whether the iterator is `const` or not isn't very important.
- There won't be any default behaviour in the base class.
- The mechanism mustn't be bugged by inheritance: classes derived from `int` iterators should be accepted as a return type as well, since they meet the requirements. I don't think this is an issue, because transitivity, but still.
- Ideally, the `begin` and `end` methods should be forced to have the same iterator type in a given derived class.
- Even more ideally, I'd like to avoid using Boost for things like `enable_if`. The library is written using C++11 (at least I try).

Comment: Does performance matter?  If it does, type erasing iteration on a per-element basis is a bad idea.

Comment: `boost::any_iterator`

Answer (score 1):

How about instead providing an interface that lets users do whatever they want with the data, but without using iterators?

```
class LibraryClass {
public:
    virtual void visitInts(std::function<void(int)> f) = 0;
};

class UserClass : public LibraryClass {
public:
    void visitInts(std::function<void(int)> f) override {
        for (int data : m_vec)
            f(data);
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vec;
};
```

You lose the ability to, say, `std::binary_search`, but you mostly have the same versatility without forcing a particular storage mechanism on the `UserClass`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sadly a generic walk isn't quite what I need: there's nothing for `f` to do on the integers in my case. The library retrieves them for further processing, something that cannot be enclosed *(cleanly)* within either `LibraryClass` or `UserClass`, and which isn't user-defined.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Why not?  pass in `[&](int x){ vec.push_back(x); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the iterator a virtual class as well, e.g. (not tested, and obviosly incomplete):

```
class LibraryClass {
protected:
  struct IteratorBase { // user needs to implement this:
     virtual const int& deref() const = 0;
     virtual void increment() = 0;
     virtual void decrement() = 0;
     // further methods, e.g., comparison and maybe cloning
  };
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IteratorBase> intsBegin_() const = 0;
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IteratorBase> intsEnd_() const = 0;
public:
  class Iterator {
    friend class LibraryClass;
    std::unique_ptr<IteratorBase> iter;
    Iterator(std::unique_ptr<IteratorBase>&& iter_) : iter(std::move(iter_) {}
  public:
    const int& operator*() { return iter->deref(); }
    const Iterator& operator++() { iter->increment(); return *this; }
    // further operators ...
  };
  Iterator intsBegin() const { return Iterator(intsBegin_()); }
  Iterator intsEnd() const   { return Iterator(intsEnd_(); }
};
```

I'm not really sure this is worth the effort, especially since you will get a lot of indirection even for very simple tasks. I guess you should rather re-think your design ...

Comment: I do have an alternative which changes the design, but it makes the whole thing less interoperable (I'm writing code to interface other libraries, which don't really play nice and clean). I guess I could define an iterator interface and make it rather transparent using operator overloading ; it might actually serve other purposes. I'll wait a bit more before I accept an answer.

Comment: Another alternative is of course static polymorphism (i.e., essentially template everything) -- but you seem not to want that.

Answer (score 0):

An any iterator isn't hard to write.  It is usually a bad idea if you care about performance, because every operation requires non-zero overhead to do the type erasure.

Suppose you only need to support `for(:)` loops and "input" iteration.

```
namespace any_iteration_support {
  template<class VTable, class...Ts>
  VTable create() {
    VTable retval;
    VTable::template populate<Ts...>(retval);
    return retval;
  }
  template<class VTable, class...Ts>
  VTable const* get_vtable() {
    static VTable vtable = create<VTable, Ts...>();
    return &vtable;
  }
  struct input_iterator_vtable {
    void(*next)(void*) = 0;
    void(*dtor)(void*) = 0;
    void(*copy)(void* dest, void const* src) = 0;
    void*(*clone)(void const* src) = 0;
    bool(*equals)(void const* lhs, void const* rhs) = 0;
    template<class It>
    static void populate( input_iterator_vtable& vtable ) {
      vtable.next = [](void* ptr){
        auto& it = *static_cast<It*>(ptr);
        ++it;
      };
      vtable.dtor= [](void* ptr){
        auto* pit = static_cast<It*>(ptr);
        delete pit;
      };
      vtable.copy= [](void* dest, void const* src){
        auto& destit = *static_cast<It*>(dest);
        auto const& srcit = *static_cast<It const*>(src);
        destit = srcit;
      };
      vtable.clone= [](void const* src)->void*{
        auto const& srcit = *static_cast<It const*>(src);
        return new It(srcit);
      };
      vtable.equals= [](void const* lhs, void const* rhs)->bool{
        auto const& lhsit = *static_cast<It const*>(lhs);
        auto const& rhsit = *static_cast<It const*>(rhs);
        return lhsit == rhsit;
      };
    }
  };
  template<class T>
  struct any_input_iterator_vtable:input_iterator_vtable {
    T(*get)(void*) = 0;
    template<class It>
    static void populate(any_input_iterator_vtable& vtable) {
      input_iterator_vtable::populate<It>(vtable);
      vtable.get = [](void* ptr)->T{
        auto& it = *static_cast<It*>(ptr);
        return *it;
      };
    }
  };
}
template<class T>
struct any_input_iterator {
  any_iteration_support::any_input_iterator_vtable<T> const* vtable = 0;
  void* state = 0;
  template<class It,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<It, any_input_iterator>::value, int> =0
  >
  any_input_iterator( It it ):
    vtable(any_iteration_support::get_vtable<any_iteration_support::any_input_iterator_vtable<T>, It>()),
    state( new It(std::move(it)) )
  {}
  any_input_iterator(any_input_iterator&& o):
    vtable(o.vtable),
    state(o.state)
  {
    o.vtable = 0; o.state = 0;
  }
  any_input_iterator& operator=(any_input_iterator&& o) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(vtable, o.vtable);
    swap(state, o.state);
    return *this;
  }
  any_input_iterator(any_input_iterator const& o) {
    if (!o.vtable) return;
    state = o.vtable->clone(o.state);
    vtable = o.vtable;
  }
  any_input_iterator& operator=(any_input_iterator const& o) {
    if (!vtable && !o.vtable) return *this;
    if (vtable == o.vtable) {
      vtable->copy( state, o.state );
      return *this;
    }
    clear();
    if (!o.vtable) {
      return *this;
    }
    state = o.vtable->clone(o.state);
    vtable = o.vtable;
    return *this;
  }
  explicit operator bool()const { return vtable; }
  friend bool operator==(any_input_iterator const& lhs, any_input_iterator const& rhs) {
    if (!lhs && !rhs) return true;
    if (!lhs) return false;
    if (lhs.vtable != rhs.vtable) return false;
    return lhs.vtable->equals( lhs.state, rhs.state );
  }
  friend bool operator!=(any_input_iterator const& lhs, any_input_iterator const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
  T operator*() const {
    return vtable->get( state );
  }
  any_input_iterator& operator++() {
    vtable->next(state);
    return *this;
  }
  any_input_iterator operator++(int) {
    auto retval = *this;
    ++*this;
    return retval;
  }
  ~any_input_iterator() { clear(); }
  void clear() {
      if (!vtable) return;
      auto dtor = vtable->dtor;
      auto s = state;
      state = 0;
      vtable = 0;
      dtor(s);
  }
  using reference = T;
  using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
  using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
};
```

this is a quick sketch of how you can type erase the concept of input iteration over a type `T`.  Much like `std::function`, this can store almost anything that satisfies the requirements of input iteration.

boost provides a similar type.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/710624d4d1364332).

You are usually better off writing a function that visits more than one node at a time per call, or even one that visits one node, in order to reduce the type-erasure overhead.  Iterators are fast because they can be inlined; with following a void pointer on every method, they can be annoyingly slow.

```
class LibraryClass {
public:
  virtual any_input_iterator<const int> intsBegin() const = 0;
  virtual any_input_iterator<const int> intsEnd() const = 0;
};
```

Of course, doing this kind of type erasure manually is tedious and error prone.  I'd use something like type erasing type erasure with a thin fascade rather than the above.

The efficient way to do it is with a span visitor

```
template<class T>
struct span {
  T* b = 0; T* e = 0;
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return e; }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  span()=default;
  span(span const&)=default;
  span& operator=(span const&)=default;
  span(T* s, T* f):b(s),e(f) {};
  span(T* s, std::size_t length):span(s, s+length) {}
};
template<class T>
using span_visitor = std::function<void(span<T>)>;

class LibraryClass {
public:
  virtual void visitInts(span_visitor<int const> f) const = 0;
};

class VecImpl : public LibraryClass {
public:
  virtual void visitInts(span_visitor<int const> f) const override {
    f( {m_vec.data(), m_vec.size()} );
  };
private:
  std::vector<int> m_vec;
};
class SimpleListImpl : public LibraryClass {
public:
  virtual void visitInts(span_visitor<int const> f) const override {
    for (int i : m_list )
      f( {&i, 1} );
  };
private:
  std::list<int> m_list;
};
class FancyListImpl : public LibraryClass {
public:
  virtual void visitInts(span_visitor<int const> f) const override {
    std::size_t count = 0;
    std::array<int, 10> buffer;
    for (int i : m_list ) {
      buffer[count] = i;
      ++count;
      if (count == buffer.size()) {
        f({ buffer.data(), buffer.size()});
        count = 0;
      }
    }
    if (count) f({ buffer.data(), count});
  };
private:
  std::list<int> m_list;
};
```

How do you consume it?

```
std::vector<int> get_ints_from(LibraryClass const& library) {
  std::vector<int> vec;
  library.visitInits([&](span<int const> ints){
    vec.append(ints.begin(), ints.end());
  });
  return vec;
}
```

This interface moves the type erasure to multiple-times-per-element to once-per-multiple-elements.

Using this approach, you get get performance approaching that of exposing the container directly, but never actually expose it.

I haven't compiled the span version yet.